# Add class to <img>s with a given src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/filename1.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="images/filename2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="images/filename3.jpg"></td>   
        <td><img src="images/filename4.jpg"></td>   
        <td><img src="images/filename5.jpg"></td>
    </tr> 
</table>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

When the user types in "filename1" in the input field and clicks the button, I want to add a class "opacity" to the img that has src containing "filename1", and the same for the rest of the img tags.

Comment: If you type `"filename1"` you want add the `opacity` class-name to the `<img>` element with that as the file in its `src`? And all other `<img>` tags? ...so why bother typing anything, why not apply that class-name to all `<img>` elements?

Comment: Please, next time try to close brackets. And you require to be more specific in your posts even in easy cases like this. Try to show your code using jsfiddle.net in order to provide better explanations in future.

Comment: @DavidThomas you did not get it. He means in each of the given cases the user types the different image names, he wants to add the class in the same way.

Comment: That text input needs a label. Those images need alt text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class like this:

```
var name = $("#input").val();
$("img[src='images/"+name+"']").addClass("opacity");
```

It will only add opacity class to the image which has src attribute like the input.

Comment: awesome this worked fine thanks just need to remove .jpg extention

Comment: @joaquingarcia or just add it into the selector.. no need for an extra function call.. ` $("img[src='images/"+name+".jpg']").addClass("opacity");` ...unless you have any other file types such as `.png`'s

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to add opacity class to all the image elements, is this correct?

If so.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  $('img').addClass('opacity')
})
```

And [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLdEqa4i8zXSt0SWYUqX?p=info)

Comment: I don't think your assumption is correct. See my comment on Muhamad's answer.

Comment: Muhamad deleted his answer. The question says when the user clicks the button, the class should be added to the image which has the filename specified in the text box in it's src.